# Saving data to a file vs. saving it to MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, file, save, connection

Using a PHP script I need to update a number every 5 seconds while somebody is on my page. So let's say I have 300 visitors, each one spending about 1 minute on the page and every 5 seconds they stay on the page the number will be changed...which is a total of 3600 changes per minute. I would prefer to update the number in my MySQL database, except I'm not sure if it's not too inefficient to have so many MySQL connections (just for the one number change), when I could just change the number in a file.

P.S.: I have no idea weather 3600 connections/minute is a high number or not, but what about this case in general, considering an even higher number of visitors. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: A clarification... Would those 3,600 changes per minute happen against the *same* file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing 3,600 reads and writes per minute against the same file is just out of question. It's complicate (you need to be extremely careful with file locking), it's going to have an awful performance and sooner or later your data will get corrupted.

DBMSs like MySQL are designed for concurrent access. If they can't cope with your load, a file won't do it better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer...btw. do you know what the actual limitations of the number of MySQL connections are and what does it depend on (besides CPU & RAM)? What's the max. connection number a MySQL DB can handle?

Comment: Besides CPU and RAM? There isn't much left: disk performance and bandwidth :) But I think you're confusing connections per minute with *simultaneous* connections; it's not the same.

Comment: Sorry for that :) Simultaneous connections is exactly what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

It will fail eventually if the user count grows but the performance depends of your server setup and other tasks that are related to this update.

You can do a slight test and open up 300 persistent connections to your database end fire up as much query's you can in minute.

If you don't need it to be transactional (the order of executed query's is not important) then i suggest you to use memcached (or redis if you need to save stuff on disk) for this instead

Comment: Is there program (or PHP script) that will give the statistics (or run the test itself) I need?

Comment: well just set the counters and run the tests with ab http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html

Answer (score 1):

files aren't transactional and you don't want to lose count so the database is the way to go

memcached's inc command is faster then the database and was the basis of i think one really fast view counting setup

if you use say a key per hour and switch so when a page view happens inc page:time occurs and you can have a process in the background collect the counts from the past hour and insert them in a database if the memcache fails you might lose the count for that hour but you will not have double counted or missed any and keeping counts per period gives interesting statistics

Answer (score 1):

If you save to file, you have to solve concurrency issues (and all but the currently reading/writing process will have to wait). The db solves this for you. For better performance you could use memcached.

Maybe you could do without this "do every 5s for each user" by another means (e.g. saving current time and subtracting next time the user does something). This depends on your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't even think about trying to handle this with files - its just not going to work unless you build a lock queue manager - and if you're going to all that trouble you might as well use the daemon to manage the value rather than just queue locks.

Using a DBMS is the simplest approach.

For a more efficient but massively more esoteric approach, write a single-threaded socket server daemon and have the clients connect to that. (there's a [lib here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5758-PHP-Handle-requests-to-network-servers.html) for doing the socket handling, and there's a [PEAR class](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon) for running PHP as a daemon)

Answer (score 0):

Using a dedicated temporary file will certainly be the most efficient disk access you can have. However, you will not be protected from concurrent access to the file in case your server uses multiple threads or processes. If what you want to do is update 1 number per user, then using a $_SESSION sub-variable will work, and I believe this is stored in memory, so it shouldbe very efficient. Then you can easily store this number into your database every 5 minutes per user

Comment: "in case your server uses multiple threads or processes" - do you know of a single threaded webserver which runs PHP in-process? I don't.